# javascript regex validation issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a javascript regex for the following:

1. must have at least one digit
2. must have at least one capital letter
3. must be between 8-15 characters

I have tried it like this:

```
function isStrongPassword(strInput) {
    //works well except A1aaaaaa
    var regex = /^(?=.*\d)(^[A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z]).{7,14}$/; 
    return regex.test(strInput);
}
```

This is working properly, except the fact it is not matching with `A1aaaaaa`, which is a valid input.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression fails because of `(?=.*[A-Z])`. None of the characters following the first one is upper case.

It seems this expression should suffice:

```
^(?=[^\d]*\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]).{8,15}$
```

---

Note that switching `.*` to `[^...]*` has nothing to do with your problem, but it avoids backtracking. Alternatively you could use lazy matching: `.*?`.

Comment: sir, the regex you have given works very well. I didnt get why in my case I had to give 7,14 but in your regex you did the length checking with 8,15 ?

Comment: Because in your expression, `(^[A-Za-z0-9])` already matched and consumed a character, so there would be only 7 to 14 let to match. In my expression, there are only lookaheads, which don't consume any characters, so the `.` has to match 8 to 15 times.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex was breaking because of the `(^[A-Za-z0-9])` part, which would mean that after a digit, there must be a letter or digit, and ***then*** a capital letter. This should work

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15}$/;
```

Which breaks down like this...

```
/              
^              # start match
(?=.*\d)       # is there a digit up ahead (maybe after zero or more anythings)
(?=.*[A-Z])    # is there a capital up ahead (maybe after zero or more anythings)
.{8,15}        # 8 to 15 anythings
$              # end match
/
```

Comment: I have not tried yet your answer. But my regex does match with 1Aaaaaaa , aaaaaaA1, 111Aaaa etc... I think it is not the reason.

Comment: The reason is, that it specifies a letter or number to start the regex, and then afterwards, to have a capital letter. So it does not match your test, which only has a capital at the beginning, and not after that.

Comment: oh yes, now I get your point. thanks so much for the explanation. regex is my weak side :)

Comment: regex is a dark art, usually problematic, always under-commented, occasionally indispensable.